# Angular with Okta sign in

Tags: okta, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am new to Okta and OAuth.

I tried to first do a sample tutorial and followed the same procedure as described [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/06/crud-angular-9-spring-boot-2)

I am stuck with Angular Authentication using OpenId Connect.

I have created OIDC application in my Octa Account and below is the default Authorization server:

[image]

Below is the snapshot of OIDC application in Okta

[image]

Below are the snapshots of the output and error I get :

[image]

[image]

When I click the login button, I am getting 400 Bad Request

Below is the request url :

https://dev-my-id.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id=0oa14cwbxyudJGVdr4x7&code_challenge=5QqCuQ-BjTJ7uoFVgpX2ourrL7XBxZ39WSSvvw1GDPw&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=2HbF0A4V664QRo4CXSD51XhI8cGIWBzRvVxGIzyevzhlVByLYlz3NPkBEOcd0Ld3&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fcallback&response_type=code&state=jpew68c6Nwo6skLAPqtdtf4uXxTriKJMPiat7YxDUSvCXH87GSoSa9eeQsSxEnnH&scope=openid%20profile

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the OIDC application you are using in Okta is set to active. That may be the cause of the 400 error you are seeing.